# PHP 5.2 (win.server) can't connect to Oracle 12c db

Tags: oracle12c, oci8, php-5.2

I have difficult question.
On win.server i have PHP 5.2 version. I must connect on Oracle 12c db. Procedure that i do is:

1. download oracle client 12.2
2. enable **php_oci8.dll**
3. insert PATH to
   **C:\Windows\SysWOW64\instantclient_12_2**
4. restart server

also i tried to insert **php_oci8_12c.dll** extension and put oci8_12c.dll file in php/ext directory.
When i true to run .bat file i see errors:

- "**Missing MSVCR120.ddl**" - i resolve this with put this file in /php/ext dir.
- "The procedure entry point **gc_remove_zval_from_buffer** could not be located in the dynamic link library **php5ts.dll**"

On my local pc i have php 5.6 and they work with 12c oracle.
On internet see that 5.2 version can work with 12c.

What is the potencial problem? What I can try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OCI 12c requires **PHP 5.5**, see http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/dsl/technote-php-instant-12c-2088811.html

You can try tho to install the **Visual C++ Redistributable Package**.

Because the MSVCR120.dll error can't be fixed by putting it in the ext folder.

When you use Apache and/or Console client, make sure you have enabled in both php.ini files, because they are different configurations.

You can also try the PECL OCI package from https://pecl.php.net/package/oci8

Make sure to pick the correct version, the most recent only works for PHP 7.

Comment: I start to configure OCI 12c on other server where have PHP 5.6.2 and windows server using instructions from oracle.com/technetwork/articles/dsl/… . Is need to configure Apache with these code from link ? I also before add directory for instantclient_12_2 in system properties/advanced/environment variables/PATH and see in php_info that Apache enable and use them. Is need then add path code in httpd.conf?  I'm not sure that will apache work if i add code for path  because start configuration (directory) of php and apache is maybe different. Also is mod_fcgid-2.3.9 required?

Comment: You can run PHP as a module or seperately by fast cgi. Only PHP needs the extension, not Apache.

Comment: But i configure like a write in first post. Enable extension php_oci8_12c in php.ini, put  instaclient_12_2 in C:\Windows\SysWOW64, add PATH for that directory in enviroment variables and i have only error in log:"Fatal error: Call to undefined function oci_connect()". What i maybe miss or is next step? You write "When you use Apache and/or Console client, make sure you have enabled in both php.ini"... is that mean that i need configure apache?

Comment: @MarkoAnastasijevic what is the path to your PHP configuration? And when you see `phpinfo();` what is the configuration path in there and does it load anything with OCI ?

Comment: And did you install the Visual C++ package?

Comment: I use phpinfo() and results is: Configuration File (php.ini) Path: C:\windows; Loaded Configuration File: C:\php\php.ini; Configure Command: "--with-pdo-oci=c:\php-sdk\oracle\x64\instantclient_12_1\sdk,shared" "--with-oci8-12c=c:\php-sdk\oracle\x64\instantclient_12_1\sdk,shared".  In Apache environment, path: C:\Windows\SysWOW64\instantclient_12_2;  On this win.server i have visual C++ 11.0 version.

Comment: I also tried to change httpd.conf like descripted on link, and add mod_fcgid.so but apache won't' start with that configuration.

Comment: Apache does not need configuration, you don't need fcgi if you run PHP as a module (which you do obviously). Only PHP configuration must be done. Do you have two configuration, one in C:\windows\php.ini and one in C:\php\php.ini ? Make sure you have a line like this somewhere: `extension=php_oci8_12c.dll`. In phpinfo() you should see a line like `OCI8 Support enabled` if everything works.

Comment: I check and in C:\windows don't have php.ini file, only in C:\php (where i enable extension=php_oci8_12c.dll like you write). In phpinfo only have oci8 in "Configure Command" right at the beginning of the page and nowhere else.  On my PC (php 5.6) i have special section in phpinfo where see OCI8 and "OCI8 Support - enable". What can be problem to don't see that on server in phpinfo?

Comment: @MarkoAnastasijevic I don't know, seems everything right... try to copy the file from c:\php\php.ini to c:\windows\php.ini and restart apache, maybe this works

Comment: I try copy php.ini. Also i try to copy oci.dll from instaclient_12_2 to c:/php/ (i see that can be problem if oci.dll was in that folder from other version oracle, but don't see in my case). Also changed PATH in environment from C:\windows\SYSwow64\instaclient to c:\instaclient... same error "Fatal error: Call to undefined function oci_connect()". The same script i test on local pc and work.

Comment: @MarkoAnastasijevic the oci dll must be in PHP extensions folder, you can try to copy instaclient folder to c:\windows\system but other then that I have no more ideas. Get a linux server, they are better and easier :D :D

Comment: In architecture (phpinfo) that is x64, complier visual c++ 2012 MSVC11, Apache Version  Apache/2.4.10 (Win64) PHP/5.6.2  (tried x86 and x64)
Because php and apache is x64 is correct to use 64bit version? Now when i start .bat file see that miss MSVCR120.dll , i put that file c:/php and now don't see in cmd that library php_oci8_12c not found and don't show miss file. i have new error: "Warning: oci_connect(): OCIEnvNlsCreate() failed. There is something wrong with your system - please check that PATH includes the directory with Oracle Instant Client libraries". Oci8 is now enabled in phpinfo.

Comment: To sum up. I now put instaclient_12_2 (tried x86 and x64) in c:/php and C:\Windows\SysWOW64. Put mscvcr120.dll in c:/php. I see on oracle site that for 12_2 need visual c++ 2013 and for 12_1 visual c++ 2010. On server dont have 2013, and because that now i'm try instaclient_12_1 and same problem (need msvcr120.dll and not load php_oci8_12c), i put msvcr120.dll and see when i run script ": "Warning: oci_connect(): OCIEnvNlsCreate() failed.....". Is this problem with i think with visual c++ or PATH?

Comment: @MarkoAnastasijevic Looks like the PHP extension cannot find the instantclient. Copy the instantclient folder to system32 folder in windows and try again please

Comment: I put 12_1 (x64) in system32 path and same error. I have report php --ri oci8 : oci8
OCI8 Support => enabled
OCI8 DTrace Support => disabled
OCI8 Version => 2.0.9
Revision => $Id: 74e302c766329dcc183df9ea0359f73
Oracle Run-time Client Library Version => 0.0.0.
Oracle Compile-time Instant Client Version => 12.1

Comment: Is sure that mod_fcgid not need? I think that not because i run php direct (cmd). I try different path and every time i get same warning. Can be problem that i tried 64 and 32bit version and windows has picked up some library? On that server have visual 2008/2010/2012, is that potential problem?

Comment: OCI8 Support enabled -> perfect. No you dont need fcgi. Apache has nothing to do with PHP modules. I guess you have different php.ini files (1 for command line, 1 for apache) make sure both work and have OCI8 enabled.

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to install it, with some miracle because i do like this much time...

Steps what i do is:

- download instaclient12.2 (32bit)
- install visual c++ redistributable 2013
- put instaclient_12_2 in C:\Windows\SysWOW64\
- insert PATH C:\Windows\SysWOW64\instantclient_12_2
- download **oci8_2.0.12 X64 TS** and put **php_oci8_12c.dll** in php/ext
- put  oci.dll (from instantclient_12_2 (32bit)) in C:\Apache24\bin,  C:\php\ext and C:\php
- enable extension php_oci8_12c.dll ini php.ini

On servers was Windows server 2008 R1 and PHP 5.6.2 TS